# Confused the parameters value in passing to function in c++

Tags: c++

I have this code :

```
 BSTR xmlst1=SysAllocString(L"*****");
 BSTR xmlst2=SysAllocString(L"*****");

  MakeXML(CMD_CMD,CMD_AUTHENTICATE,&xmlst1);
//should be xmlst1=<CMD>Authen</CMD>

  MakeXML(XPassword,Password,(&xmlst2));
//should be xmlst2=<Pass>1234</Pass>
```

when I check the result with showmessage:

```
ShowMessage(xmlst1);//this is the result <Pass>1234</Pass>
ShowMessage(xmlst2);// strange character.
```

the value of xmlst2 is in xmlst1. but why?
and why the value of xmlst2 is a strange character?

UPDATED:

```
STDMETHODIMP TVinaImpl::MakeXML(BSTR XMLCodec, BSTR XMLVal, BSTR* res)
{
  try
  {
  wcscpy(*res,L"<");wcscat(*res,XMLCodec); wcscat (*res,L">");
  wcscat(*res,XMLVal);
  wcscat(*res,L"</");wcscat(*res,XMLCodec); wcscat (*res,L">");
  }
  catch(Exception &e)
  {
    return Error(e.Message.c_str(), IID_IVina);
  }
  return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: You are passing an address, not ny reference.

Comment: This can't be answered unless you tell us what `MakeXML` is and the value of the variables you pass to it.

Comment: You're using `delete[]` on a local variable. That's bad. Only `delete` what you `new`.

Comment: By doing `*res=wcs1` you're effectively returning the address of a local variable. As soon as the function returns, the pointer becomes invalid.

Comment: so I should change `wchar_t` to `BSTR`

Comment: That's not the whole story. Don't hack around with a BSTR. Obey Microsoft ;-) See my answer.

Comment: This ain't such a bad question not it's been edited. Not sure the -4 is an good reflection on the question quality,

Comment: I'm not familiar with `BSTR` but you calling something called `SysAllocString` and then overwriting the returned pointer looks like you're leaking memory.

Comment: @melpomene: You're correct. You need to balance with `SysFreeString`.

Comment: @Bathsheba It shows no research effort (just "my values are wrong somehow, halp") and it's missing a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sysfreestring does not free memory immediately . and also I should use BSTR because I just use C++Builder and make activex library for C# program . in the .ridl for string type I can just select BSTR,LPSTR and ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `BSTR` is a nasty beast. It's essentially a unicode string with a hidden prefix that yields the string length. Your error is essentially in the line `*res = wcs1;`. You can't assign a BSTR in this way. Futhermore `delete[] wcs1;` isn't going to end well either. Don't attempt to delete a variable with automatic storage duration!

Your best bet is to use the `_bstr_t` type which contains overloaded operators for assignment, and specific functions for copying. Else use the "heavier" `CComBSTR`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6.aspx

If these are not available to you then you can always access the String API directly: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221105(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: in c++builer does not know _bstr_t

Comment: Which is still wrong. If you can't use `_bstr_t` then use the api directly. I've added the link to the answser.